# Javascript - block all pop up and new window, for the following websites

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to block the pop up ads and new window ads, i have add this code to my extension but is not working, this code block some ads but not all pop up ads, what i need to change here to block all pop up ads, and if is posible and new windows ads? thanks

```
var topNames=["(_2)","(aCsdAh)","(admaven)"];
for(var i=0;i<topNames.length;i++){
var topName = topNames[i];
var regex = new RegExp(topName,"g");
if(window.top.name.match(regex)){
window.stop();
window.close();
}}
var domains=["35\.184\.137\.181", "159\.203\.92\.22", "ad4game\.com", "openload\.co", "oload\.tv", "oload\.stream", "upvid\.co", "streamango\.com", "streamcherry\.com", "adnetworkperformance\.com", "adplxmd\.com", "adrunnr\.com", "adsjudo\.com", "afftrack\.com", "agisdayra\.com", "alwaysthrifty\.club", "applicationg29\.com", "archermedia\.co\.uk", "artadtags\.com", "as\-popup\.ir", "bestadbid\.com", "bwin(.*)wm\=", "click\-cpa\.net", "clickd\.club", "clickppcbuzz\.com", "clicksgear\.com", "codeadnetwork\.com", "codeonclick\.com", "danarimedia\.com", "datumglobal\.com", "di7wee8\.top", "dinozavr\.online", "directrev\.com", "dl\.www\.speedvid.net", "done\.witchcraftcash\.com", "dota2spotlight\.club", "doublepimpssl\.com", "elvenar\.com", "engine\.spotscenered\.info", "gearbest\.com", "getdcgreatdeals\.com", "hearthstonehighlights\.org", "heroesreplay\.info", "hotsspotlight\.club", "jolic2\.com", "kd2244\.com", "kitx\.gdn", "kutlvuitevgw\.com", "l161c\.com", "leaguehighlight\.com", "lightinthebox\.com", "locatelinks\.com", "maxprofitcontrol\.com", "mazonaws\.com", "mediabuy\.cloud", "mediawhirl\.net", "newtabtv\.com", "nextlnk2\.com", "odplbueosuzw\.com", "ohbuegh3ev\.com", "onclickpredictiv\.com", "onclkds\.com", "performanceadexchange\.com", "pipeschannels\.com", "popads\.net", "popcash\.net", "popmog\.com", "popmyads\.com", "poptm\.com", "practively\.com", "prestoris\.com", "prpops\.com", "pubdirecte\.com", "pureadexchange\.com", "redonetype\.com", "serve\.popads\.net", "soda\.media", "terraclicks\.com", "theadgateway\.com", "thewhizmarketing\.com", "thewhizproducts\.com", "tnkexchange\.com", "toponclick\.com", "trackertrk\.top", "trackmedia101\.com", "travelwithetf\.com", "u1trkqf\.com", "venturead\.com", "voodaith7e\.com", "webgains\.com", "www\.cloudy\.ec", "xxlargepop\.com", "yoursinfo\./info", "zedo\.com", "zhabyesrdnvn\.com", "zryydi\.com"];
for(var i=0;i<domains.length;i++){
var domain = domains[i];
var regex = new RegExp(domain,"g");
if(document.URL.match(regex)){
window.stop();
window.close();
document.write('');
}}
```

Comment: Why not use what is already done? https://getadblock.com/

Comment: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Justinas i want to add some javascript or jquery to my extension to block the pop up ads. thanks